# touchOverflowEnabled: true leads to problems with a dialog on iPad

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog

I want to open a dialog in combination with touchOverflowEnabled: true.

The problem is the following:
The dialog is coming up properly but after a couple of milliseconds, the background below the dialog turns from black into white; the page seems to shrink. 
Furthermore, the checkboxes on the main page are smaller; they do not fit the complete page from left to right.

If I do not use touchOverflowEnabled: true everything works well.

Any ideas, how to solve this problem??

Here's my complete sample code (the html-tags are missing):

```
<head> 
    <title>Title</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/icon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/tablet_startup.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/black-tie/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.extend(  $.mobile , {
          touchOverflowEnabled: true,
          defaultDialogTransition: 'pop',
          orientationChangeEnabled: false
        })
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <!-- Begin objective page -->
  <section id="questions_objectives" data-role="page">

      <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
          <h1>Goals</h1>
      </header><!-- /header -->

      <div data-role="content">
          <form id="f_objectives">
              <h3>Personal Goals</h3>
              <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="o_1" id="o_1">
                      <label for="o_1">Goal 1</label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="o_2" id="o_2">
                      <label for="o_2">Goal 2</label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="o_3" id="o_3">
                      <label for="o_3">Goal 3</label>
                  </fieldset>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div><!-- /content -->

      <footer data-role="footer" data-id="pluginFooter" data-position="fixed">
          <div align="center" data-role="controlgroup" data-iconpos="top" data-type="horizontal">
              <a href="#logout_panel" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Abmelden</a>
          </div>
      </footer><!-- /footer -->

  </section><!-- /page -->
  <!-- End objective page -->

  <!-- Begin logout page --> 
  <section id="logout_panel" data-role="dialog">

      <header data-role="header">
          <h1>Logout</h1>
      </header><!-- /header -->

      <div id="section_logout" name="section_logout" data-role="content">
          <h3>Would you like to receive emails?</h3>
          <form id="logout_form">
              <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="logout_yes" id="logout_yes" checked="checked" onchange="setLogoutCB('YES')">
                      <label for="logout_yes">Yes</label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="logout_no" id="logout_no" onchange="setLogoutCB('NO')">
                      <label for="logout_no">No</label>
                  </fieldset>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div><!-- /content -->

      <footer data-role="footer">
          <div id="btn_logout" align="center" data-role="controlgroup" data-iconpos="top" data-type="horizontal">
              <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse">Logout</a>
          </div>
      </footer><!-- /footer -->

  </section>
  <!-- End logout page -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would recommend u not to use touchOverflowEnabled anymore. It has its own issues and it wont even be there in jquery mobile from the version 1.1 
its going to be deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Do you know any other technique in order to get such smooth transitions like touchOverflowEnabled has provided?

Answer (score 0):

there,
In my opinion all your problems come from the jQuery version that you have been using - 1.7

According to the [JQM blog](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/)

> Reminder: 1.0 supports jQuery core 1.6.4 only
>
> Since 1.7 was just recently released and has some significant changes (and improvements), only 1.6.4 is officially supported at this time. We plan on adding 1.7 support when we release version 1.1.

When I use touchOverflowEnabled with 1.6.4 there seems to be no problems as you explained above.
There is still a small bug with iPad and touchOverflowEnabled - the dialog is only half page height but this is also easy fixed with single line of css

```
.ui-mobile [data-role="dialog"]{height: 100%;}
```

I hope all this is useful :)

Best Regards, 
Mihail